# Oracle SQL: Use REGEXP_SUBSTR to extract text before specific words

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Using Oracle sql, I want to extract the text before certain words. I need to exclude text starting at and following the word "exceed" or "max".

Example: "Take 1-2 tabs 4-6 hours. Do not exceed 5 tabs per day"

Desired Output: "Take 1-2 tabs 4-6 hours. Do not"

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking `regexp_instr()` with `substr()` rather than `regexp_substr()` directly:

```
select x.*,
       substr(str, 1, regexp_instr(str || 'max', 'exceed|max') - 2)
from (select 'Take 1-2 tabs 4-6 hours. Do not exceed 5 tabs per day' as str from dual) x
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the desired output by using nested `regexp_substr()`, like so:

```
select trim(regexp_substr(
    regexp_substr('Take 1-2 tabs 4-6 hours. Do not exceed 5 tabs per day','.*(exceed|max)'),
    '.*[^(exceed|max)]'
  )) desired_output
from dual;
```

But if you need the whitespaces before the "exceed" or "max", just remove the `trim()`.

Reference: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php